# How to look for a substring in a string with certain rules using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like below

```
Hello there how are you?
```

I want to look for the substring `'there how'` in the string. So I would do something like this

```
import re
string = "Hello there how are you?"
term = "there how"
print(re.search("\s" + term + "\s",  string).group(0)). # /s is used to ensure the match should be an independent phrase
```

But now the problem is, if I get a variation of the string, then the match doesn't occur. For example for strings like this

If there is a large amount of space between the words

```
Hello there         how are you?
```

If certain letters are capitialized

```
Hello There How are you?
```

What I want to do is to ensure as long as the substring `'there how'` is present in the string as a separate phrase (not like `Hellothere how are you?` or `Hello there howare you?` etc), I should be able to find a match.

How can I achieve the objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may replace spaces with `\s+` in the `term` and use a case insensitive matching by passing `re.I` flag:

```
import re
ss = ["Hello there how are you?", "Hello there         how are you?", "Hello There How are you?"]
term = "there how"
rx = re.compile(r"(?<!\S){}(?!\S)".format(term.replace(r" ", r"\s+")), re.I)

for s in ss:
    m = re.search(rx,  s)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

Output:

```
there how
there         how
There How
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9AbJzJ)

**NOTE**: If the `term` can contain special regex metacharacters, you need to `re.escape` the `term`, but do it before replacing spaces with `\s+`. Since spaces are escaped with `re.escape`, you need to `.replace(r'\ ', r'\s+')`:

```
rx = re.compile(r"(?<!\S){}(?!\S)".format(re.escape(term).replace(r"\ ", r"\s+")), re.I)
```

JavaScript solution:

```js
var ss = ["Hello there how are you?", "Hello there         how are you?", "Hello There How are you?"];
var term = "there how";
var rx = new RegExp("(?<!\\S)" + term.replace(/ /g, "\\s+") + "(?!\\S)", "i");
for (var i=0; i<ss.length; i++) {
    var m = ss[i].match(rx) || "";
    console.log(m[0]);
}
```

Comment: @Wikton wow! This solution handles all kind of variations. Thanks!

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you but my team wants to get this implemented in javascript. Basically user will press a button and then this check has to be done. Any idea how your solution can be implemented in javascript? It would be of great help to me. Do you want me to create a separate question and tag you there?

Comment: @SouvikRay Please check the JS solution. This is just a demo, you will need to implement the rest yourself.